# How do I come by this pty and what can I do with it?

Tags: shell, terminal, io-redirection, tty, pty

It seems that a simple shell redirect from `/dev/ptmx` gets me a new pseudo-terminal.

```
$ ls /dev/pts; ls /dev/pts </dev/ptmx
0  1  2  ptmx
0  1  2  3  ptmx
```

It disappears as soon as the process that owns the fd claim on `/dev/ptmx` quits, but it is simple enough to retain it:

```
$ PS1='<$(ls -1 "$@" /dev/pts/*|uniq -u)> $ ' \
  exec 3<>/dev/ptmx "$0" -si -- /dev/pts/*
</dev/pts/3> $ ls /dev/pts; exec 3>&-
0  1  2  3  ptmx
<> $ ls /dev/pts; exec 3<>/dev/ptmx
0  1  2  ptmx
</dev/pts/3> $ exit
```

So it looks like the simple `open()` on `/dev/ptmx` is enough to get a pseudo-terminal. I guess that would make the shell - *(or the process for which it does the redirect)* - the owner of the master side of the pty.

But how do I assign the slave side - or *can* I assign the slave side? And if I can - what can I do with it? Can I affect its read/write/flush timings w/ `stty`? Will a slave side process link  through to my new pty when referencing `/dev/tty`?

Comment: Do the [`pts(4)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/pts.4), [`ptsname(3)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ptsname.3), [`grantpt(3)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/grantpt.3) and [`unlockpt(3)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ptsname.3) manpages help?

Comment: Could someone explain the first line to me: `PS1='<$(ls -1 "$@" /dev/pts/*|uniq -u)> $ ' exec 3<>/dev/ptmx "$0" -si -- /dev/pts/*`. What do "$@" & "$0" refer to here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, as @muru points out in the comments, there doesn't seem to be a simple way to interface the pty created for you with just the shell. I managed all of it but the `unlockpt()` part. According to something I read [here](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-18-sect-6) it may be there are some compile-time options in the kernel for disabling newly created pty locking, but I didn't want to do that. So, I did something else.

I didn't need `grantpt()` actually. According to the description found [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Allocation.html#Allocation) all it does is change the UID/GID for `/dev/pts/[num]` device file. But according to `man mount` there are easier ways to handle that. Here are some `devpts` mount options:

- `uid=value` and `gid=value`

  - This sets the owner or the  group  of  newly created  PTYs to the specified values.  When nothing is specified, they will  be  set  to the  UID  and  GID  of the creating process. For example, if there is a  *tty*  group  with  GID  5,  then `gid=5` will cause newly created PTYs to belong to the *tty* group.

That was already the case on my system by default. But after reading that I realized I might want to make a change after all. The very next section reads:

- `ptmxmode=value`

  - Set the mode for the new ptmx device node in the `devpts` filesystem.
  - With the support for multiple instances of `devpts` (see `newinstance` option above), each instance has a private ptmx node in the root of the `devpts` filesystem *(typically `/dev/pts/ptmx`)*.
  - For compatibility with older versions of the kernel, the default mode of the new ptmx node is `0000`.   `ptmxmode=value`  specifies  a more useful mode  for the ptmx node and is highly  recommended  when  the `newinstance` option is specified.

While it would have worked without doing so, I liked the idea and set that to `0640` as recommended in the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/devpts.txt). The kernel doc link, by the way, elaborates on the `newinstance` mount option - which is pretty cool and basically enables you get a separately name-spaced group of ptys per `/dev/ptmx` mount.

Anyway, so the *something else* amounted mostly to:

```
mount -o remount,newinstance,gid=5,ptmxmode=0640 /dev/pts
mount --bind /dev/pts/ptmx /dev/ptmx
```

...as the kernel docs recommend - see the link about why. I also made the effect of the above commands permanent by adding a couple of lines to my `/etc/fstab`.

And...

```
<<\C cc -xc - -o pts
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        if(unlockpt(0)) return 2;
        char *ptsname(int fd);
        printf("%s\n",ptsname(0));
        return argc - 1;
}
C
```

Which just compiles a tiny little C program that attempts to call `unlockpt()` on its stdin and if successful prints the name of the newly created and unlocked pty to `stdout` or else silently returns 2.

Once that was done I could create my own *screened* processes like:

```
exec 3<>/dev/ptmx
```

...to get the master-side fd in the current shell then...

```
(setsid -c "$0" -i 2>&1|tee log) <>"$(./pts <&3)" 3>&- >&0 &
```

That gets an interactive shell running on the other end of the pseudo-terminal in the background. It will interpret anything printed to `>&3` as user input.

```
mikeserv@localhost$ echo echo hey >&3
mikeserv@localhost$ cat log
$ hey
$
mikeserv@localhost$ echo echo hey >&3
mikeserv@localhost$ cat log
$ hey
$ hey
$
```

Which basically nets me a backgrounded, logged, interactive interpreter *(or anything else I might care to run on these)* ala `screen` without so much overhead and on any file descriptor I choose.

The master-side fd owned by my current shell is the only means of serving the slave-side input and is only writable by my current shell process *(and its children)*. I can communicate with the other end by writing to `>&3` and I can either read from same or from a log file as  I wish.

And `stty` does work on the terminal after all:

```
mikeserv@localhost$ echo stty -a ">$(tty)" >&3
speed 38400 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;                                      
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>;
swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W;
lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc
-ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl
echoke
```

Comment: Does remounting devpts as a new instance invalidate existing pts devices?

Comment: @muru - not for me. I did it all in the same terminal window - still got one of them open now. But the fstab stuff is the way to go. When you want a private set of ptys you do it - perhaps w/ `unshare` - without `remount` though - you mount a *new* `devpts` instance anywhere else. So your private set will start at 0 again... or wait...? Is that right? Now i forget if its the whole `devpts` or just `ptmx`. Still trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Thanks. This is one thing that I think I'll be using for setting up chroots from now on.

Comment: @muru - im still playing around with it too. Right now ive got `fc` writing the last executed command-line to my current shell's `">$(tty)"` in the background shell's `$PS1` eval. Still, though, this was just about curiosity at first and mostly still is. You can already do most of this w/ `bash/ksh` *coprocesses* *(via pipes)* and far better w/ `zsh` tricks like `zpty`. But all of that is always so huge - and if im going to bg a shell its probably *not* going to be `zsh` and especially not `bash` - they're both big and slow.