# Is it possible to establish a Socket session (between Server and Client) using shell commands?

Tags: shell, command-line, socket

From what I read (only the very outline, i do not know C Language) a Socket session is established between a server and a client by calling functions for both of them in a certain order.

```
It starts with the Server:
socket()     #creates communication point
bind()       #gives this communication point an address
listen()     #tells it to be ready for some signal

then the Client:
socket()
connect()    #establishes a line between himself and the listening Server

now both can talk with each other by using read() and write().
```

Well, this was implemented in the C Programming Language, but could this be done also with the Shell and if so would it make any sense doing it this way?

Answer (score 2):

There are several programs for making socket connections from the command line (or via a shell script). The most common is probably netcat, of which there are at least three implementations:

- Original one ©1995-1996 Avian Research (Hobbit's netcat). No good upstream link I'm aware of, so here it is  in the Debian package tracker: https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/netcat
- Netcat6, a rewrite. Now declared obsolete; http://www.deepspace6.net/projects/netcat6.html
- netcat-openbsd, a rewrite by the OpenBSD project. **Probably the one you want.** Code can be seen at http://bxr.su/openbsd/usr.bin/nc/
- socat, not a rewrite but the same idea, with many additional features. **Another good choice** if you need all the features and don't mind the additional complexity. http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/

The manual page gives many examples, for example here's how (based on a far more scary example in the man page) you can run `bc` over a socket:

```
mkfifo /tmp/f && cat /tmp/f | bc -i 2>&1 | nc -l 127.0.0.1 1234 > /tmp/f
```

Then you can connect to that network `bc` using:

```
nc localhost 1234
```

Or with `socat`, it's:

```
socat EXEC:'bc -i' TCP4-LISTEN:1234,bind=127.0.0.1   # server
socat - TCP4:127.0.0.1:1234                          # client
```

Comment: There's also a netcat spin-off called [ncat](http://nmap.org/ncat).

Comment: @Scott indeed. And several more, including an optional bash feature, at least a kernel patch or two, etc. Feel free to edit in any you find important...

Comment: The most interesting one I didn't mention is probably socat, I'll add that one in later tonight.

Comment: ^ yes ^ please do, That's the one I immediately thought of when reading the question. Following the train here, I think `socat`'s command of ptys is particularly relevant to `bc`. As an aside, a method I generally find convenient when working w/ `mkfifo` is get an fd on the pipe then deleting the link before going further. Like `mkfifo pipe; exec 3<>pipe; rm pipe; <&3 bc | nc >&3 &`. It saves the cleanup later and is more secure, I think.

Comment: @mikeserv socat added. I'll note though that your immediate pipe cleanup isn't really any safer—both are only safe if file permissions keep an attacker from opening the pipe or `rm`'ing it (and replacing with something else, like a symlink) before the intended code opens it

Comment: This is true, and is why I often prefer to hack a pipe out of the shell instead. Or better, to get a [pty](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/179030/52934). You can set the `-m`ode of course *(had to look it up - it uses the symbolic modes I guess which I find more difficult than 700 but apparently `go-wr` should do similar)* but it probably still wants cleaning up eventually - which is usually my primary impetus.