# How to forward between processes with named pipes?

Tags: shell, pipe, fifo, buffer

The `/tmp/in`, `/tmp/out` and `/tmp/err` are named pipes, already created and opened by some process (for reading, writing and writing, respectively).

I would like to create a new process that pipes its stdin into `/tmp/in`, and writes the contents of `/tmp/out` to its stdout, and the contents of `/tmp/err` to its stderr as they become available. Everything should work in a **line buffered** fashion. The process should exit when the other process, that created `/tmp/in`, stops reading and closes `/tmp/in`. The solution should work on Ubuntu, preferably without installing any extra package. I would like to solve it in a bash script.

---

[mikeserv](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/52934/mikeserv) pointed out that without an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), it is hard to understand what I want. So, below is an SSCCE, but keep in mind that it is a minimal example so it is pretty silly.

**The original setup**

A parent process launches a child process and communicates with it through the child's stdin and stdout line-by-line. If I run it, I get:

```
$ python parent.py 
Parent writes to child:  a
Response from the child: A

Parent writes to child:  b
Response from the child: B

Parent writes to child:  c
Response from the child: C

Parent writes to child:  d
Response from the child: D

Parent writes to child:  e
Response from the child: E

Waiting for the child to terminate...
Done!
$
```

parent.py

```py
from __future__ import print_function
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import os

child = Popen('./child.py', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
child_stdin  = os.fdopen(os.dup(child.stdin.fileno()), 'w')
child_stdout = os.fdopen(os.dup(child.stdout.fileno()))

for letter in 'abcde':
    print('Parent writes to child: ', letter)
    child_stdin.write(letter+'\n')
    child_stdin.flush()
    response = child_stdout.readline()
    print('Response from the child:', response)
    assert response.rstrip() == letter.upper(), 'Wrong response'

child_stdin.write('quit\n')
child_stdin.flush()
print('Waiting for the child to terminate...')
child.wait()
print('Done!')
```

child.py, **must be executable!**

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
from sys import stdin, stdout

while True:
    line = stdin.readline()
    if line == 'quit\n':
        quit()
    stdout.write(line.upper())
    stdout.flush()
```

**The desired setup and a hackish solution**

Neither the parent's source file nor the child's source file can be edited; it is not allowed.

I rename the child.py to child_original.py (and make it executable). Then, I put a bash script (a proxy or a middle man if you wish) called child.py, start the child_original.py myself before running `python parent.py` and have the parent.py call the fake child.py which is now my bash script, forwarding between the parent.py and the child_original.py.

The fake child.py

```bash
#!/bin/bash
parent=$$
cat std_out &
(head -n 1 shutdown; kill -9 $parent) &
cat >>std_in
```

The `start_child.sh` to start child_original.py before executing the parent:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
rm -f  std_in std_out shutdown
mkfifo std_in std_out shutdown
./child_original.py <std_in >std_out
echo >shutdown
sleep 1s
rm -f  std_in std_out shutdown
```

The way of executing them:

```
$ ./start_child.sh & 
[1] 7503
$ python parent.py 
Parent writes to child:  a
Response from the child: A

Parent writes to child:  b
Response from the child: B

Parent writes to child:  c
Response from the child: C

Parent writes to child:  d
Response from the child: D

Parent writes to child:  e
Response from the child: E

Waiting for the child to terminate...
Done!
$ echo 

[1]+  Done                    ./start_child.sh
$
```

This hackish solution works. As far as I know, it does not meet the line buffered requirement and there is an extra shutdown fifo to inform the start_child.sh that child_original.py has closed the pipes and start_child.sh can safely exit.

---

**The question asks for an improved fake child.py bash script, meeting the requirements (line buffered, exits when the child_original.py closes any of the pipes, does not require an extra shutdown pipe).**

---

---

**Stuff I wish I had known:**

- If a high-level API is used for opening a fifo as a file, it must be opened for *both reading and writing*, otherwise the call to `open` already blocks. This is incredibly counter-intuitive. See also [Why does a read-only open of a named pipe block?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5782279/341970)
- In reality, my parent process is a Java application. If you work with an external process from Java, read the stdout and stderr of the external process from *daemon* threads (call `setDamon(true)` on those threads *before* starting them). Otherwise, the JVM will hang forever, even if everybody is done. Although unrelated to the question, other pitfalls include: [Navigate yourself around pitfalls related to the Runtime.exec() method](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html).
- Apparently, unbuffered means buffered, but we don't wait until the buffer gets full but flush it as soon as we can.

Comment: Did you try doing the forwarding in bash while running bash with stdbuf? E.g.,` forward() { while read line; do echo "$line"; done; }
forward </tmp/out &
forward </tmp/err >&2 &
forward >/tmp/in
`

Comment: Nice question and researches. looking forward  to the answers.

Comment: @PSkocik I have dropped an e-mail to your e-mail address. Please let me know if it hasn't arrived yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get rid of the killing and shutdown stuff (which is unsafe and you may, in an extreme, but not unfathomable case when `child.py` dies before the  `(head -n 1 shutdown; kill -9 $parent) &` subshell does end up `kill -9`ing some innocent process),
then `child.py` won't be terminating because your `parent.py` isn't behaving like a good UNIX citizen.

The `cat std_out &` subprocess will have finished by the time you send the `quit` message, because the writer to `std_out` is `child_original.py`, which finishes upon receiving `quit` at which moment it closes its `stdout`, which is the `std_out` pipe and that `close` will make the `cat` subprocess finish.

The `cat > std_in` isn't finishing because it's reading from a pipe originating in the `parent.py` process and the `parent.py` process didn't bother to close that pipe.  If it did, `cat > stdin_in` and consequently the whole `child.py` would finish by itself and you wouldn't need the shutdown pipe or the `killing` part (killing a process that isn't your child on UNIX is always a potential security hole if a race condition caused due to rapid PID recycling should occur).

Processes at the right end of a pipeline generally only finish once they're done reading their stdin, but since you're not closing that (`child.stdin`), you're implicitly telling the child process "wait, I have more input for you" and then you go kill it because it does wait for more input from you as it should.

In short, make `parent.py` behave reasonably:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import os

child = Popen('./child.py', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)

for letter in 'abcde':
    print('Parent writes to child: ', letter)
    child.stdin.write(letter+'\n')
    child.stdin.flush()
    response = child.stdout.readline()
    print('Response from the child:', response)
    assert response.rstrip() == letter.upper(), 'Wrong response'

child.stdin.write('quit\n')
child.stdin.flush()
child.stdin.close()
print('Waiting for the child to terminate...')
child.wait()
print('Done!')
```

And your `child.py` can be as simple as

```
#!/bin/sh
cat std_out &
cat > std_in
wait #basically to assert that cat std_out has finished at this point
```

(Note that I got rid of that fd dup calls because otherwise you'd need to close both `child.stdin` and the `child_stdin` duplicate).

Since `parent.py` operates in line-oriented fashion, gnu `cat` is unbuffered (as mikeserv pointed out) and `child_original.py` operates in a line oriented fashion, you've effectively got the whole thing line-buffered.

---

**Note on Cat:** Unbufferred might not be the luckiest term, as gnu `cat` does use a buffer. What it doesn't do is try to get the whole buffer full before writing things out (unlike stdio). Basically it makes read requests to the os for a specific size (its buffer size), and writes whatever it receives without waiting to get a whole line or the whole buffer.  ([read(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) can be lazy and give you only what it can give you at the moment rather than the whole buffer you've asked for.)

(You can inspect the source code at http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/cat.c ; `safe_read` (used instead of plain `read`) is in the `gnulib` submodule and it's a very simple wrapper around [read(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) that abstracts away `EINTR` (see the man page)).

Comment: @Ali : the last chapter means that, as you have 2 line buffered programs (and especially the last one is!), the resulting output of the 3 will be line oriented as well. If your last program is buffered (add a `| grep ^`) then the resulting output to your terminal or file would be block buffered.

Answer (score 2):

With a `sed` the input will always be read in on a line-buffer, and the output can be explicitly flushed per line with the `w` command. For example:

```sh
(       cd /tmp; c=
        mkfifo i o
        dd  bs=1    <o&
        sed -n w\ o <i&
        while   sleep 1
        do      [ -z "$c" ] && rm [io]
                [ "$c" = 5 ]   && exit
                date "+%S:%t$((c+=1))"
        done|   tee i
)
```

---

```
44: 1
44: 1
45: 2
45: 2
46: 3
46: 3
47: 4
47: 4
48: 5
48: 5
30+0 records in
30+0 records out
30 bytes (30 B) copied, 6.15077 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

...where `tee` *(which is [spec'd not to block buffer](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tee.html))* writes its output to the terminal and to `sed`'s `i` pipe simultaneously. `sed` reads `i` line-by-line and `w`rites each line it reads to its `o`ut pipe as soon it does. `dd` reads the `o`ut pipe a byte at a time, and it shares a stdout with `tee`, and so they both write the output to the terminal at the same time. This would not happen if `sed` didn't explicitly line-buffer. Here's the same run but without the `w`rite command:

```
(       cd /tmp; c=
        mkfifo i o
        dd  bs=1    <o&
        sed ''  >o  <i&
        while   sleep 1
        do      [ -z "$c" ] && rm [io]
                [ "$c" = 5 ]   && exit
                date "+%S:%t$((c+=1))"
        done|   tee i
)
```

---

```
48: 1
49: 2
50: 3
51: 4
52: 5
48: 1
49: 2
50: 3
51: 4
52: 5
30+0 records in
30+0 records out
30 bytes (30 B) copied, 6.15348 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

In that case `sed` block buffers, and doesn't write a thing to `dd` until its input closes, at which point it flushes its output and quits. In fact, it exits when its writer does in both cases, as is witnessed in `dd`'s diagnostics being written at pipeline's end.

Still though...

```
(       cd /tmp; c=
        mkfifo i o
        dd  bs=1    <o&
        cat >o      <i&
        while   sleep 1
        do      [ -z "$c" ] && rm [io]
                [ "$c" = 5 ]   && exit
                date "+%S:%t$((c+=1))"
        done|   tee i
)
```

---

```
40: 1
40: 1
41: 2
41: 2
42: 3
42: 3
43: 4
43: 4
44: 5
44: 5
30+0 records in
30+0 records out
30 bytes (30 B) copied, 6.14734 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

Now my `cat` is a GNU version - and GNU's `cat` *(if called without options) never* block buffers. If you are also using a GNU `cat` then it seems pretty clear to me that the problem is not with your relay, but with your Java program. However, if you are *not* using a GNU `cat`, then there is a chance that it will buffer output. Lucky for you, though, there is but only one [POSIX spec'd option to `cat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cat.html), and that is for `-u`nbuffered output. You might try it.

I'm looking at your thing, and after playing around with it awhile I'm pretty sure your problem is a deadlock situation. You've got the one `cat` hanging on input there at the end, and if the JVM process is also waiting for someone to talk to it, then probably nothing will ever happen. So I wrote this:

```
#!/bin/sh
die()   for io  in  i o e
        do      rm "$io"
                kill -9 "$(($io))"
        done    2>/dev/null
io()    while   eval "exec $((fd+=1))>&-"
        do      [ "$fd" = 9 ] &&
                { cat; kill -1 0; }
        done
cd /tmp; fd=1
mkfifo   i o e
{   io <o >&4 & o=$!
    io <e >&5 & e=$!
    io >i <&3 & i=$!
}   3<&0  4>&1  5>&2
trap "die; exit 0" 1
echo; wait
```

It's kind of sloppy about handling return codes, unfortunately. With more work it could be made to do so reliably though. Anyway, as you can see it backgrounds *all* of the `cat`s, writes an empty line to stdout, then `wait`s until one of the `cat`s quits, which should set off a chain that kills all of them in all cases, I think.

Comment: Thanks. It seems rather convoluted. :( Now, if I run the Java application - external process combo without my proxy bash script in the middle, *"the buffers are properly flushed on both sides, they never hang"* as I write in my question. It is unclear to me why they hang if I put my bash script in the middle. I have GNU `cat`; I have double-checked (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS).

Comment: @Ali - Well, w/ ubuntu, you definitely have a GNU `cat`. And yes, it is rather convoluted. I wanted only to show reproducibly and unmistakably that `date | tee >i (cat|sed) >o dd >tty` would come out as soon as it went in. There are many portable options for avoiding block buffers in a pipeline, and (`tee`|`dd`|`cat`|`sed`) are the best of these. I don't know *why* your issue arises, either. It seems strange to me as well, but you don't make it very clear exactly (where|when|how|why) io comes and goes. *Java VM* and *external process* don't help much, I'm afraid. *What external process*?

Comment: I would like to test your solution but I would like to ask you to please put your answer as a standalone shell script on the top of your answer. Does it satisfy the line buffered requirement of the question? Since `dd` does not read line-by-line, I am afraid it doesn't.

Comment: As for my failed attempt with my silly shell script: I could try to make a minimal example and put all the source code, e.g., on GitHub. Are you willing to debug this issue? If you are, then I probably do it, otherwise I won't waste my time chasing this wild goose. In any case, the problem only appears if I run it with that silly shell script so the bug is most likely there.

Comment: @Ali. I think so. I've been playing with some stuff. Please see the edit I just posted.

Comment: Unfortunately, your most recent edit is way beyond my level of understanding of shell scripts, sorry. :( Please answer my previous two questions that I asked in comments.

Comment: @Ali - Well, neither `cat` nor `dd` would do *line-buffered* output - they'll both write out the sizes of the blocks they read in. I set `dd`'s blocksize to a single byte - which is slow, but sure. `sed` definitely will do line-buffered output because it always buffers input by line - if that's what you want. The bit of shell I wrote before was just to demonstrate how such tools might work in a chain - I had to provide my own input source because there's no example i/o. The sh script might work as a stand-in replacement for yours, except that it tries to create/clean-up its own pipe files.

Comment: Great, thanks, I appreciate your efforts. Unfortunately, it is not the answer that I was hoping for... :( Well, I guess my problem at hand is more difficult than it seems at first. I leave the question open for a while.

Comment: @Ali - of course you should. But I don't think you're likely to get much of an answer if you don't bother to say what you're doing. You should try to do that - and not for my sake. If you don't tell people what you do to cause a problem, how can you expect them to understand how to fix it?

Comment: Well, I can make the Java code public on GitHub. I let you know when I have those example codes ready.

Comment: I have added an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). It is unclear why my original attempt with that silly bash script failed but we will never know: My `/tmp` folder lives in the RAM and its contents are lost when I reboot my machine. In any case, please check the SSCCE and update your answer accordingly. I hope that the question is clear now. Thanks!

Comment: @Ali. Wow. That was a very good edit, i'm impressed. I think it is, though it's still a little hazy about why. Probably that doesn't matter - and that's your business - but occasionally motive can be telling clue in a solution. Doesn't matter - alphabets are fine - better than fine, it was an *excellent* edit.

Comment: I am glad you like the updated answer. There are a bunch of use cases, that is why I am vague about the motivation. Probably the most important use case is debugging: I want to run the child process in an IDE. I have no idea how to attach a debugger to a process that was not started by the IDE. The shell script in the question is sufficient for this but I am sure you can do better than that. The next thing on the agenda is to intercept the communication between two C++ applications without hurting the performance two much.

Comment: @Ali - oh that's good! But you should post it as an answer if it is an answer and accept it.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Please re-read the updated question: The hackish script in the question provides a temporary workaround but it does not answer the original question and it is a compromise (uses an extra fifo). As for my previous comment: Although it is not a use case but I wanted to learn more about pipes and find a proper solution, not just some hack that works for the time being. Anyway, please update your answer given the new information.

Comment: @Ali Oh, ok. It's 'just, in the last comment you called it an answer... Anyway, I'll try it up. No promises - I have developed a rather strong distaste for Python.

Comment: Ooops, sorry, that was a typo... :( I meant to write *updated question*. Let me know if you have difficulties understanding the python example. I think if you run it first, you will better understand what's happening.

Comment: FYI: I have started a bounty on this question.

Comment: @Ali - is there anything useful to you [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/215803/52934)?

Comment: PSkocik's second answer is almost an answer. However, I did some benchmarking, and interesting things are happening: Line buffering makes matters worse! For example the line buffered `sed -n w\ o <i&` in your answer performs worse than the corresponding unbuffered `cat` command. Please check the updated question!

Comment: @Ali: line buffering instead of whole block(s) buffering is probably less efficient, this is normal. Just the "look for a newline" is less efficient than just copy n bytes. and the block-buffer sizes are custom-sized to be the most efficient in the most cases.

Comment: @Ali - I know. It's why i didn't stop at `sed` - `cat` is better. But if you implemented the solution in kernel space, in a pty, line-buffering would be automatic and efficient. Doing this w/ pipes is possible, but difficult, and prone to error. It's why there is such a thing as a pty at all. It's how `screen` works. It's how your thing should, too. Please look again at the link in my last comment.

Comment: @OlivierDulac - amen, but just so we don't confuse the already 17-deep comment thread, `cat` copies its in-block to an out-block as soon as it is received, whereas standard C-lib *block-buffering* is to withhold output until it equals at least some *size* of a block at least - and it's typically 4k or so.

Comment: @mikeserv Sorry, I could get back to this question earlier, I have been busy with work. Yes, I read your other linked answer but I did not understand it, and I did not see how it related to my question. You vastly overestimate my understanding of Linux. :( Anyway, the `cat` solution is fast enough, I can pump 3GB of data through it in 0.8 seconds. That's more than enough; there is no need for more sophisticated solutions. Anyway, +1, and thanks for your help and patience!

Answer (score 0):

In bash, you could try:

```
forward() { while read line; do echo "$line"; done; } 
forward </tmp/out & 
forward </tmp/err >&2 &
forward >/tmp/in
wait
```

and then run the script with `stdbuf -i0 -oL`.

The `forward` function is basically your the `pipe` method from your python code with src and dest defaulting to stdin and stdout and without the explicit flushing, hoping that `stdbuf` might do it.

If you're already concerned about performance and want it in C code, put it in C code. I'm not familiar with a stdbuf friendly `cat` alternative but here's a C++ one liner (almost) for `cat`ting `stdin` to `stdout`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() { for(string line; getline(cin,line); ){ cout<<line<<'\n'; }; }
```

Or if you absolutely must have C code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  const size_t N = 80;
  char *lineptr = (char*)malloc(N); //this will get realloced if a longer line is encountered
  size_t length = N;
  while(getline(&lineptr, &length, stdin) != -1){
    fputs(lineptr, stdout);
  }
  free(lineptr);
  return 0;
}
```

Neither the C nor the C++ example do explicit flushing after each line, because I think leaving that to `stdbuf` is a better design decision, but you could always add that by calling `fflush(stdout)` in the C example after each line, replacing `'\n'` with `endl` in the C++ example, or more efficiently, by pre-setting the buffering to line buffering in both cases so you don't have to make those "expensive" C/C++ function calls.

Comment: The script can be just a call to stdbuf with the actual echoing script/program as an argument.